# React-native pass data from child to parent just works in init

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes, react-native-component

I have a screen that shows a few items in list. my item are a component called CardItem which has couple of buttons. I implemented like above but when i run my project, component pass my desired data which is id to parent method in init status, but i need it when user click on that button.

Parent:

```
addItemQuantity = (id) => {
  console.log('ADD item quantity with id: ', id);
};

render() {  
   return (
      <CardItem
         data={item}
         index={idx}
         key={item._id}
         addItemQuantityPress={this.addItemQuantity}
      />
   )
```

}

child:

```
handleAddItemQuantity = (id) => {
  console.log('child component method');
  this.props.addItemQuantityPress(id);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.cardItemOperation} >
            <TouchableHighlight
                underlayColor="#ffffff"
                onPress={this.handleAddItemQuantity(this.props.data._id)}
                style={styles.icon} >
            <Image
                style={styles.icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={require('./images/icon-add.png')} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
    )
}
```

Output when i run the project:

> child component method
>   ADD item quantity with id:  5a2660924713cf6c8d088424
>   child component method
>   ADD item quantity with id:  5a1a58cacd0b8a0febce9fd7
>   child component method
>   ADD item quantity with id:  5a1a5856cd0b8a0febce9fd5
>   child component method
>   ADD item quantity with id:  5a4c8e9d2ebcf507323e7b73
>   child component method
>   ADD item quantity with id:  5a1a5862cd0b8a0febce9fd6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it written there,

```
this.handleAddItemQuantity(this.props.data._id)
```

Will get executed immediately at time of render. Change this to:

```
onPress={() => {this.handleAddItemQuantity(this.props.data._id)}}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Irfy..why it get executed immediately without clicking. Can you explain?